# How I can debug two-language program?

Tags: python, c++, eclipse

I use Python as a high-level wrapper and a loaded C++ kernel in the form of a binary library to perform calculations. I debug high level Python code in IDE Eclipse in the usual way, but how do I debug C++ code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What compiler built the C++ module?

Comment: What environment do you use to develop this C++ library? Is it a separate project in the Eclipse workspace that also contains the Python project? Then perhaps it can be possible to set breakpoints or in the code.

Comment: If nothing else, you can always use *"printf" debugging* where your C++ library just logs events and information to some debugging log file.

Comment: You can normally "attach" an IDE's debugger to a program, so if you have the C++ project open in the debugger, tell it to attach to the python program (which is running), and put in a breakpoint in the C++ code, you should be able to debug.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, gcc, but I can use a different compiler if it is critical

Comment: ChrisMM, Python creates many processes, so I don’t understand how to attach a C++ library to Python?

Comment: Some programmer dude, At this moment I'm using Qt Creator for C++ development and Eclipse for Python. But I can do everything in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try using gdb's "attach " command (or "gdb -p " command-line option) to attach to the python process that has the C++ kernel library loaded.

Comment: Thank you! In Qt Creator I use "Start and Debug External Application".